# How can I listen on TextView and make changes to the same TextView in android

Tags: java, android

I tried the following code, but [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) doesn't let me do that, as I'd enter into an infinite loop.

```
mEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.input_content);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   //I want to format the already existing text in s in a certain way as      the user is typing
                   mEditText.setText(s.toString() + " \n");
            }       
        });
```

Please any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: What exactly you want to do? on which condition, you want to edit text inside `afterTextChanged`?

Comment: what exactly you want to do please elaborate clearly ... ?

Comment: Is this the above code that triggers an infinite loop ?

Comment: @MysticMagic I have updated the code in `public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }` is the exact code, the text formatting sequence is more complicated than that but, thats a representative example of what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @Darkie I have updated the code in `public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }` is the exact code, the text formatting sequence is more complicated than that but, thats a representative example of what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @ToYonos I have updated the code in `public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }` is the exact code, the text formatting sequence is more complicated than that but, thats a representative example of what I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

3 possible solutions :

1. Check for the carriage return presence in the string

Like this :

```
mEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.input_content);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        //I want to format the already existing text in s in a certain way as      the user is typing
        if (s.toString().charAt(s.length() - 1 ) != '\n')
        {
            mEditText.setText(s.toString() + " \n");
        }
    }
});
```

Not the best solution, according to what's in your input string

2. Do it in beforeTextChanged

Like this :

```
mEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.input_content);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        //I want to format the already existing text in s in a certain way as      the user is typing
        mEditText.setText(s.toString() + " \n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

3. Cancel the listener, temporarily

Like this :

```
final TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        //I want to format the already existing text in s in a certain way as      the user is typing
        mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(tw);
        mEditText.setText(s.toString() + " \n");
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    }
});

mEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.input_content);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I think removing and adding the TextWatcher Listener is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely entering an infinite loop because you are changing the text in `public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)` which then causes the method to be called again.
The best solution would be to change the text in one of the other methods, or on the loss of focus of the editable. See [View.OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) for more details on this.

Here is an example:

```
textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            textView.setText(s.toString() + " \n");
        }
    }
});
```